# Detect completion of sharing to social networks using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

I'm trying to detect the ending of sharing to instagram through `UIDocumentInteractionController`. It's opening modal window (*see screenshot below*) and I want to know when it's dismissed.

[image: sample]

`UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` doesn't help.

Comment: you should present the controller.

Comment: why does the delegate not help? there are functions called on dismissal